# Symfony3 automatic locale routing

Tags: php, routes, locale, symfony

I have a problem with routing for locales.

www.example.com/ -> don't work (No route found for "GET /")

www.example.com/en/ -> works

In my case should this the same. English is the default language and I want to serve the page in English if www.example.com is called.
I always receive an error (No route found for "GET /") when I call the page without the locale.

routing.yml

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type: annotation
prefix: /{_locale}
```

config.yml

```js
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

DefaultController.php

```js
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use AppBundle\Entity\Page;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }


}
```

This works, but it's not sexy

```js
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     * @Route("/{_locale}/", name="homepage_locale")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: add exactly what you want, it's not clear

Answer (score 1):

## JMSI18nRoutingBundle

To achieve that what you want I used once [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle). It allows you to translate your routes for each locale and also it manages your prefix in URL.

Example of YAML configuration:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [de, en]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Then your URLs would look like this:

```
- /de/contact # Locale: de
- /contact    # Locale: en
```

Or if you define translation for routes (both URLs still point to the same location!):

```
- /de/kontakt # Locale: de
- /contact    # Locale: en
```

[There](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration) is more information about how to configure this bundle, how you can extend its.

## Symfony way

In `routing.yml` file you should define routes:

```
app.locale:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
```

Then Symfony first is looking for route with locale. It is important to remember that routes from `api.locale` are first in matching pattern, then when you would have route named `example.com/go` (like GO to store but shorten) then Symfony try to find locale `go`. To prevent this, you can use `requirements` parameter:

```
app.locale:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: en|de
```

It's not DRY way, you need to define any route twice (with and without locale).

Using `defaults` in configuring route do not helps because Symfony Routing adds any parameter if it is required. With `defaults` path `example.com` should works but if you go to `example.com/about`, Symfony adds parameter `_locale` to URI and result will be `example.com/en/about`

[EDIT] Important thing also is how Symfony's Routing works. We have first route `app.locale` with prefix `/{_locale}` and second `homepage` with path `/`. The summary path would be `example.com/{_locale}/`, not `example.com/{_locale}`. The trailing slash is important in building URIs.

Without that, path `example.com/de` is looking for route in `app` and it cannot find any similar to `de`.

There you have probably solution for trailing slash: [Redirect URLs with a Trailing Slash](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html)